# Workarounds for emulating UDFs for window aggregates in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I'm trying to write custom aggregate functions in BigQuery. In PGSQL, I can write [user-defined aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xaggr.html) which can be used with `over` clause, but I'm not able to write any such aggregate functions for BigQuery - would it be possible to write a function that takes in an entire array of a column of a partition and return a value based on some custom calculation?

Example of what I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temp_db.temp_func(arr ARRAY<int64>)
RETURNS int64 LANGUAGE js AS """
  return arr.length*10 //example calculation
  //actual result involves looping over the array and doing few calculations 
""";

select s_id, temp_db.temp_func(s_price) over (partition by s_id order by s_date rows 40 preceding) as temp_col
from temp_db.s_table;
```

This gives an error: `Query error: Function temp_db.temp_func does not support an OVER clause at [6:19]`

The [existing aggregate functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions) are not sufficient for my purpose so I need to be able to execute custom calculation over custom window sizes. Are there any workarounds for this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temp_db.temp_func(arr ARRAY<int64>)
RETURNS int64 LANGUAGE js AS """
  return arr.length*10 //example calculation
  //actual result involves looping over the array and doing few calculations 
""";

select s_id, temp_db.temp_func(ARRAY_AGG(s_price) over (partition by s_id order by s_date rows 40 preceding)) as temp_col
from temp_db.s_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This will work for me. Do you have any idea how this compares with a native PGSQL aggregate UDF in terms of performance?

Comment: somehow I think there should not be a performance impact - rather than difference related to different engines - just my guess

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out soon!

Comment: I have one more related question: Would it be possible to maintain some sort of a state variable that is shared from window to another? For example, if I want to use the first window's result in the computation of the result of the next window, how would I do that in BigQuery (the first variable in aggregate function in PGSQL does exactly this)?

Comment: just as a part of above solution - i don't think so! but if you can post new question with all related details, example(s) - we can try to find a solution - usually we do :o)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836317/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-shared-state-between-windows-when-using-udfs-in-bigquer 
^ I've posted a new question. Please take a look when you can!

Comment: sure. confirmed :o)