# Is it possible to keep a shared state between windows when using UDFs in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

This is a follow up question to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63829262/workarounds-for-emulating-udfs-for-window-aggregates-in-bigquery/63830704?noredirect=1#comment112882353_63830704) about being able to emulate aggregate functions (like in PGSQL) in BigQuery.

The solution propsed in the previous question does indeed work for cases where the function applied on each window is independant of the previous window - like calculating simple average etc., But when calculating recursive functions like exponential moving average, where the formula is:
`EMA[i] = price[i]*k + EMA[i-1]×(1−k)`

Using the same example from the previous question,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temp_db.ema_func(arr ARRAY<int64>, window_size int8)
RETURNS int64 LANGUAGE js AS """
    if(arr.length<=window_size){
        // calculate a simple moving average till end of first window
        var SMA = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
            SMA = SMA + arr[i]
        }
        return SMA/arr.length
    }else{
        // start calculation of EMA where EMA[i-1] is the SMA we calculated for the first window
        // note: hard-coded constant (k) for the sake of simplicity
        // the problem: where do I get EMA[i-1] or prev_EMA from?
        // in this example, we only need the most recent value, but in general case, we would 
        // potentially have to do other calculations with the new value 
        return curr[curr.length-1]*(0.05) + prev_ema*(1−0.05)
    }
""";

select s_id, temp_db.ema_func(ARRAY_AGG(s_price) over (partition by s_id order by s_date rows 40 preceding), 40) as temp_col
from temp_db.s_table;
```

Storing state variable as a custom type is very easy in PGSQL and is a part of the aggregate function parameters. Would it be possible to do emulate the same functionality with BigQuery?

Comment: how many rows in your `temp_db.s_table` table?

Comment: ~65 million at the moment. Partitioned on a field called 'date_month' which is just 'YEAR-MONTH-01' for all dates. It's a table of EOD prices for ~22k tickers. I've not mentioned anything about partitioning or filter query to simplify the question.

Comment: so the EMA calculation will be within specific partition - right? what the size (number of rows) for /per partition?

Comment: I wouldn't say one partition, but potentially a group of partitions. Since each partition is 1 month of EOD data for all the symbols in the table, I'd say that's about 20,000*25 trading days = ~500,000 records per partition. If the EMA's period is > 25 or so, naturally, more partitions would be used right?

Comment: sure. I meant calculation for all partition, but per/within partition. p.s. doesn't mean I have suggestion yet :o) just trying to clarify use case

Comment: A single EMA is the simplest example I could think of for my application. More examples of requirement would be - several similar UDFs in several sub(potentially sub-sub)-queries and conditional matching with columns - like ema_15>close and rsi_30<another_udf_col,.. etc., I've done all of this in PGSQL, but the more I start to think about porting everything to BQ, I realize that without proper user-defined aggregate function architecture, it's either not possible or is going to be terribly inefficient. But I know nothing about BQ, so I'll wait for your answer :)

Comment: i don't think it can be done generically for BigQuery and rather wanted to see the specific case and see if some reasonable workaround is possible. Meantime, again recursiveness and aggregate UDF is some thing that is not supported [hopefully yet] in BQ, so you might want to submit respective feature request(s). Meantime checkout [BQ scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) but i don't think your case will fit there

Comment: That's unfortunate. You can post your last comment as an answer and I'll accept it since the answer to my question is now technically a "No".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't think it can be done generically for BigQuery and rather wanted to see the specific case and see if some reasonable workaround is possible. Meantime, again recursiveness and aggregate UDF is something that is not supported [hopefully yet] in BQ, so you might want to submit respective [feature request(s)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659).

Meantime checkout [BQ scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) but i don't think your case will fit there

Comment: I'm writing the feature request now.
I've just been looking at BQ scripting and it might be able to solve other use-cases I have. 
Thanks for the discussions!